# Docker networking: use the default bridge through a rootless container

Tags: networking, docker

### Introduction

I have an issue with network in docker root-less.

I have a folder named `rounting-docker` a docker-compose with 2 services:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
    ngnix:
        image: ngnix
        ports:
            - 8080:80
    
    cmdline:
        image: ubuntu
```

I want from the `cmdline` container to curl the ngnix container.

---

### Rootless test

I start my ngnix server: `docker-compose up -d ngnix`

So it automatically create the network `routing-docker_default` with the network 172.28.0.0/16

The ngnix container is assigned the ip: `172.28.0.2`

I then start my `cmdline` container `docker-compose run --rm cmdline`

And from the `cmdline` container I can access my ngnix only with `curl 172.28.0.2`

And from my computer I can access the ngnix page through the following url:

```bash
localhost:8080
127.0.0.1:8080
192.168.25.54:8080 #My computer ip

172.17.0.1:8080 #172.17.0.0/16 is the default bridge network for docker

127.28.0.2 #which seems logic according to the fact that my docker network is 172.28.0.0/16
```

---

### Rootfull test

I start my ngnix server: `docker-compose up -d ngnix`

So it automatically create the network `routing-docker_default` with the network 172.23.0.0/16

The ngnix container is assigned the ip: `172.23.0.2`

I then start my `cmdline` container `docker-compose run --rm cmdline`

And from the `cmdline` container I can access it through:

```bash
172.23.0.2 #the ip of the ngnix container
172.23.0.1:8080 #the "router" foy my routing-docker_default network
172.17.0.1:8080 #the "router" for the default docker network
192.168.25.54:8080
```

And from my computer I can access the ngnix page through the following url:

```bash
localhost:8080
127.0.0.1:8080
192.168.25.54:8080 #My computer ip

172.17.0.1:8080 #172.17.0.0/16 is the default bridge network for docker
127.23.0.2 #which seems logic according to the fact that my docker network is 172.23.0.0/16

172.23.0.2 #the ip of the ngnix container
172.23.0.1:8080 #the "router" foy my routing-docker_default network
172.17.0.1:8080 #the "router" for the default docker network
```

---

### What I expect/ I want

In rootless mode, I would like to access the `ngnix` container from the `cmdline container` through the ip: `172.17.0.1`

I want this to have the exact same network addressing on my prod/dev environnement.

I hope it's clear enough. I have put all the debug processing I have done. I hope I'm not missing anything.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Greg Askew for correcting my errors. However, concerning the IPs, I'm talking about 127 and not 172.
it's working using 127.X.X.X but not using 172.X.X.X

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Attention, the following answer is for a system in which dockerd runs under the root account (it is not rootless)

**Original answer**

Consider using networks other than default. In the following example, the nginx is accessed from 192.168.27.100 from whatsoever environment

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    networks:
      cust_network:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.27.100

  cmdline:
    image: ubuntu
    networks:
      - cust_network

networks:
  cust_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.27.0/24
```

If you do a grep to see the bridge interfaces before executing docker-compose, you see:

```
$ ip a | grep -A 2  "[0-9].*br-"
$
```

As you can see, there is no bridge interface in the host. However, after launching docker-compose:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Starting test_nginx_1   ... done
Starting test_cmdline_1 ... done
$ ip a | grep -A 2  "[0-9].*br-"
5: br-03317adad668: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
   link/ether 02:42:75:73:52:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   inet 192.168.27.1/24 brd 192.168.27.255 scope global br-03317adad668
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 fe80::42:75ff:fe73:5248/64 scope link 
---
1: vetha4d6986@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-03317adad668 state UP group default 
   link/ether 36:de:ab:19:93:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
   inet6 fe80::34de:abff:fe19:934a/64 scope link
```

You can verify that the port is open with nc

```
$ nc -zv 192.168.27.100 80
192.168.27.100: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host
(UNKNOWN) [192.168.27.100] 80 (http) open
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposition, that's what I have done. Still I want to understand why...

Comment: I'm coming back after a few days, I was on something else. It's not working for me.
Using your example, from `cmdline` I can access ngnix only on `192.168.27.100` whereas on my `host`, I can only access it trough `172.17.0.1:8080`
Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: The file configures the port 8080 from host to the port 80 of the container nginx. As 172.17.0.1 is an address of the host, that is the expected behaviour. When you define cust_network, your PC creates an IP adapter for the new bridge network. So you may access the container through this IP in 192.168.27.100:80 . Yes, the port 80, not the 8080, in the same way than cmdline.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your explications, this is inedeed the expected behavior. I have tried to access the web page at `192.168.27.100:80` but it's not working. I can not either ping this ip from my host. Is it working for you ?

I'm also quite surprised because I do not have any `veth` or `br` interface. 

I'm thinking about creating a route or openning some ports, somewhere between my host and docker to allow my container to reach on other one on `172.17.0.1`. What do you think ?

Comment: Yes, when you configure a new network of type bridge, you can see a new adapter in your host. Now I cannot add snippets. This evening (in Spain) I will try

Comment: I have just edited my answer to show you the effect in a Linux VM

Comment: Hello @j-m-robles, sorry for the delay, I was working on an other project.
Can you confirm me you are running docker rootless ? 
I can reproduce the exact same behavior using docker rootfull.
However, it's impossible for me to reproduce it using a rootless docker.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I made use of vagrant debian-12 machines. I thought that dockerd was executed under the docker account, but I have seen that it doesn't . The dockerd process run under the root account.